# Mat chip list select single ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-material

I display some chips within a chiplist:

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let rockBand of this.rockBands"
   [disableRipple]="true"
   [selected]="rockBand.selected"
   (click)="this.toggleSelection(rockBand)">{{ rockBand.name }}</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

When the user clicks on a chip the following function is being called:

```
public toggleSelection(rockBand: RockBand): void {
  rockBand.selected = !rockBand.selected;
}
```

Switching the selected value, however, results in the following error:
*ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'attr.aria-selected': 'true'. Current value: 'null'.*

I know that the `mat-chip-list` has an input property called `multiple` which indicates whether the user should be allowed to select multiple chips. In my scenario, the user should only be able to select one chip at a time so just like radio buttons, and deselect it if the chip was already selected. Changing the click function to the following does work:

```
public toggleSelection(rockBand: RockBand): void {
  const shouldSelect = !rockBand.selected;
  this.rockBands.forEach(band => band.selected = false);
  rockBand.selected = shouldSelect;
}
```

This solution is suboptimal since this requires iterating over all entries and resetting the selected value to false.
Is there another and possibly better way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Two oversights :

1. Never use template variables as `this.rockBands` simply `rockBands` works well.
2. The logic in the first `toggleSelection` is not correct. You're toggling the `selected` flag of the clicked chip but not resetting the flag for chip which is already selected. Next time if user wants to select that chip again , they'll need to click twice.
   (I would say second approach is better)

TL;DR

add below code :

```
 import { ChangeDetectorRef, AfterContentChecked} from '@angular/core';
      constructor(private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
                
                  ngAfterContentChecked() {
                    this.cdref.detectChanges();
                  }
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xekmqq?file=src/app/chips-drag-drop-example.ts)

why I am getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` :

So the mechanics behind change detection actually works in a way that both change detection and verification digests are performed synchronously. That means, if we update properties asynchronously the values will not be updated when the verification loop is running and we will not get ExpressionChanged... error. The reason we get this error is, during the verification process, Angular sees different values then what it recorded during change detection phase.

[A good Read about this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I see that the ngAfterContentChecked lifecycle hook does the trick. Selecting and deselecting chips does not behave consistently. When I click on apple then on banana and then back to apple I have to click twice.

Comment: Yeah..  see my second point in the answer. Your pogic Logic isn't right.

Comment: I see what you mean. But if I change the logic which handles the click action and also deselect the already selected chip I don't need the ngAfterContentChecked lifecycle hook right?

Comment: Yes you don't need. I gave that example to clear your doubt .